# React Native key issue

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I'm building a FlatList in React Native. Every row in the list is an Accordion component ([github here](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-collapsible)) with Header and Content sections. However I'm getting the unique "key" prop error below:

[image]

I've read a lot about key properties [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34576332/warning-each-child-in-an-array-or-iterator-should-have-a-unique-key-prop-che) and [here](https://medium.com/react-native-development/how-to-use-the-flatlist-component-react-native-basics-92c482816fe6), and tried to implement key properties on my components. The related code parts on my list are:

1. I have a datasource as follows. An array, whose each object having name, number and key fields.

   ```
   [
       {
           "name": "Credit Card",
           "number": "123456",
           "key": 0
       },
       {
           "name": "Bank Account",
           "number": "222222",
           "key": 1
       },
       ...
   ]
   ```
2. FlatList component:

   ```
   <FlatList
     data={filteredList}
     keyExtractor={item => item.key}
     renderItem={({item}) => _renderAccordion(item)}
   />
   ```

   I've added the keyExtractor as suggested in the docs.
3. Each row in the flat list is rendered with an Accordion component:

   ```
   var _renderAccordion = function(item) {
       return(
           <Accordion 
               sections={[item]}
               key={"accordion"+item.key}
               renderHeader={_renderHeader}
               renderContent={_renderContent}
               underlayColor={colors.white}
           />
       );
   }
   ```

   The accordion component has the key prop.
4. Headers of accordion are rendered as follows:

   ```
   var _renderHeader = function(item) {
       return (
           <View key={"header"+item.key}>
               <Text>{item.name}</Text>
           </View>
       );
   }
   ```

   I've added a unique key prop to the headers in case.
5. The contents of accordion are rendered as:

   ```
   var _renderContent = function(item) {
       return (
           <View key={"content"+section.key}>
               <Text>{item.number}</Text>
           </View>
       );
   }
   ```

Each key I used in components are unique and I think I have added keys to all required parts. But I'm still getting the error. What could I be missing? Thanks in advance.

Comment: does the warning go if you remove sections={ [item] } ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try in your code

**Flatlist Component**

```js
<FlatList
  data={filteredList}
  keyExtractor={item => ''+item.key}
  renderItem={({item}) => _renderAccordion(item)}
/>
```

The warning should be dismissed after change key from number to string.

Reference to [React Native Flatlist Document](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist.html#keyextractor)

```js
keyExtractor: (item: ItemT, index: number) => string
```

Comment: The warning has gone. Thank you :)

Comment: You could also do `{item => String(item.key)}` - bit more explicit.