# How to fix Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop

Tags: reactjs, firebase, redux

I'm creating a simple app using React , Redux and Firebase.
When I go to my Notification list in browser there is a warning message in console

Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.
Check the render method of ' ProjectList '.

'ProjectList' is one of my component in my application.

How can I remove/fix this warning message ?

[image]

[image: "Index.js File"]

[image]

[image]

[![enter image description here][5]][5]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Warning: Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop. Check the render method of \`ListView\`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34576332/warning-each-child-in-an-array-or-iterator-should-have-a-unique-key-prop-che)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to do what it says, and add a `key`. It looks like you've added a key to each `<ProjectSummary />` but when you map over an array and return a list of components, the key needs to be on the outermost element - in this case the `<Link key={project.id}>`

You don't need it on the ProjectSummary itself.

Comment: can you tell me the code what I need to change and how can I do that. am a beginner for this stack.
Thank you Brett

Comment: Yep, like I said above, remove `key={project.id}` from the `<ProjectSummary>` component and add it to the Link - `<Link key={project.id} to={'/project/' + project.id}>`. This is in the render method of your ProjectList.js file - lines 11 and 12.

Answer (score 3):

**Just add the 'key' attribute** at the uppermost Element and assign the **index** value to it. Add index as an argument in map() function.

```
{ props.posts.map((post, index) => <ProjectSummary key={index} name={post.name} />) }
```