# Warning - Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop

Tags: reactjs, key, parent-child

Got a **Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.** I cant figure out which key I need to use.

```
<td className="banana-td">
                    {todos.map((todo, index) => (
                        <BananaBullet
                            key={index.id}
                            value={todo.date}
                            completed={todo.completed}
                            onClick={() => 
           toggleTodo(todo.id)}
                        />
                    ))}
                </td>

                <td className="task-td">
                    {todos.map((todo, index) => (
                        <TodoContainer
                            key={index.id}
                            text={todo.text}
                            completed={todo.completed}
                            toggleTodoItem={() => 
          toggleTodo(todo.id)}
                        />
                    ))}
                </td>
                <td>
                    {todos.map((todo, index) => (
                        <DeadlineList
                            key={index.id}
                            value={todo.date}
                            completed={todo.completed}
                            onClick={() => 
                 toggleTodo(todo.id)}
```

I red the [react guidelines](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys), but it doesnt help me understand how to use it in my case

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Warning: Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop. Check the render method of \`ListView\`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34576332/warning-each-child-in-an-array-or-iterator-should-have-a-unique-key-prop-che)

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-night-pytse?file=/src/components/TodoList.js

Comment: Yep, it works without any issues: https://97pp0.csb.app/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`index` is a number, not an object. Just `index` is enough.

```
key={index}
```

Answer (score 2):

In your code, you have mentioned:

```
key={index.id}
```

This will not work because, `key` is a number / integer. All you need to do is:

```
key={index}
```

If I understand what you're trying to do, then you should be doing:

```
key={todos[index].id}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `todo` object has a unique field on it (`id`), so you can put in `todo.id` as the key. This is far better than using an index value, since React may get confused with ordering during state updates. Do this for the `BananaBullet`, `TodoContainer`, and `DeadlineList`. For example:

```js
<BananaBullet
  key={todo.id} // change here
  value={todo.date}
  completed={todo.completed}
  onClick={() => toggleTodo(todo.id)}
/>
```