# dev tool shows me this error "Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop." please

Tags: reactjs

```
const Experts = () => {
    const experts = [{
            img: image1,
            category: 'Dentist',
            name: 'Dr. Robartis',
            expertize: 'DMD,FACE'
        },
        {

            img: image2,
            category: 'Dentist',
            name: ' Dr. Linda Davis',
            expertize: 'CDT'
        },
        {

            img: image3,
            category: 'Dentist',
            name: 'Zakaria Smith',
            expertize: 'FACDS,DDS'
        },
        {

            img: image4,
            category: 'Dentist',
            name: 'Maria',
            expertize: 'FADG,DMD'
        }
    ]
    return (
        <div className="container" id="experts">

            <h2 className="mb-5">Award Winning Dentists</h2>
            <div className="row">
                {
                    experts.map(expert => <Expert expert={expert}></Expert>)
                }
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Experts;
```

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0CIIm.png)

Comment: `<Expert expert={expert}></Expert>` ------> `<Expert expert={expert} key={/*some unique value */} />`. Also note that this is not an error; it is a warning.

Comment: You need to pass a unique id. 
https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Warning: Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop. Check the render method of \`ListView\`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34576332/warning-each-child-in-an-array-or-iterator-should-have-a-unique-key-prop-che)

Answer (score 0):

```
 <div className="row">
        {experts.map((expert,index) => <Expert key={index} expert={expert}</Expert>)}
 </div>
```

this should help

Answer (score 0):

Just as the error states, this generated list of elements should contain a `key` property in each element:

```
experts.map(expert => <Expert expert={expert}></Expert>)
```

If the `expert` value had some identifier, such as an `id` property, then you can use that:

```
experts.map(expert => <Expert key={expert.id} expert={expert}></Expert>)
```

Otherwise, you can always rely on the index value supplied as the second argument to the `map` callback:

```
experts.map((expert, i) => <Expert key={i} expert={expert}></Expert>)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you're looping over an Array, you should pass a unique identifier as a `key` prop to each child, so that React finds and recognizes which child has changed, removed, or added. From [ReactJs docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys):

> Keys help React identify which items have changed, are added, or are removed. Keys should be given to the elements inside the array to give the elements a stable identity.

So in your case, you should pass a key to the `<Expert>` component.

For choosing an identifier, many developers use the index of the element in Array and pass it as `key` prop. In your case, it would be like the below code:

```
<div className="row">
  {
    experts.map((expert, index) => <Expert key={index} expert={expert}></Expert>)
  }
</div>
```

This approach (using `index` as a prop) is the easiest and the most feasible approach, but it's not the best approach always! Based on the [ReactJs docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys):

> We don’t recommend using indexes for keys if the order of items may change. This can negatively impact performance and may cause issues with component state.

The main reason is that if you use `index` as a `key` prop for a child component, reordering your `experts` list (by deleting an expert for example) will change the `index` for the remaining items in the `experts` list. In this case, the component state can get mixed up and may use the old key for a different child component. So basically it is recommended to avoid using `index` as a `key` prop.

If your `experts` list has a *unique* property (it can be `id` or any other unique property) for each item, you can use the following code:

```
<div className="row">
  {
    experts.map((expert) => <Expert key={expert.id} expert={expert}></Expert>)
  }
</div>
```

There are also some exceptions where you can safely use `index` as a `key` prop, as [listed here](https://programmingwithmosh.com/react/why-do-i-need-keys-in-react-lists/):

**What are some exceptions where it is safe to use index as key?**

1. If your list is static and will not change.
2. The list will never be re-ordered.
3. The list will not be filtered (adding/removing items from the list).
4. There are no `id`s for the items in the list.