# Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop. CartScreen replaces item instead of adding when add to cart button is clicked

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mern

so I've been having this issue with my web page that im unable to solve on my own. Everything works, however when I add Items to my cart instead of aadding the item it replaces the current item with that one. When I go to inspect my CartScreen it displays this error:
react-jsx-dev-runtime.development.js:87 Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.

Check the render method of `CartScreen`. See https://reactjs.org/link/warning-keys for more information.
i dont get it because I assumed that I hve a unquie key prop at Line:54 I need help if anyone knows the issue here. Here is my CartScreen code:
`

```
import { useContext } from 'react';
import { Store } from '../Store';
import { Helmet } from 'react-helmet-async';
import Row from 'react-bootstrap/Row';
import Col from 'react-bootstrap/Col';
import MessageBox from '../components/MessageBox';
import ListGroup from 'react-bootstrap/ListGroup';
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';
import Card from 'react-bootstrap/Card';
import { Link, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import axios from 'axios';

export default function CartScreen() {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const { state, dispatch: ctxDispatch } = useContext(Store);
  const {
    cart: { cartItems },
  } = state;

  const updateCartHandler = async (item, quantity) => {
    const { data } = await axios.get(`/api/products/${item._id}`);
    if (data.countInStock < quantity) {
      window.alert('Sorry. Product is out of stock');
      return;
    }
    ctxDispatch({
      type: 'CART_ADD_ITEM',
      payload: { ...item, quantity },
    });
  };
  const removeItemHandler = (item) => {
    ctxDispatch({ type: 'CART_REMOVE_ITEM', payload: item });
  };

  const checkoutHandler = () => {
    navigate('/signin?redirect=/shipping');
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Helmet>
        <title>Shopping Cart</title>
      </Helmet>
      <h1>Shopping Cart</h1>
      <Row>
        <Col md={8}>
          {cartItems.length === 0 ? (
            <MessageBox>
              Cart is empty. <Link to="/">Go Shopping</Link>
            </MessageBox>
          ) : (
            <ListGroup>
              {cartItems.map((item) => (
The key is right here:
                <ListGroup.Item key={item._id}>
                  <Row className="align-items-center">
                    <Col md={4}>
                      <img
                        src={item.image}
                        alt={item.name}
                        className="img-fluid rounded img-thumbnail"
                      ></img>{' '}
                      <Link to={`/product/${item.slug}`}>{item.name}</Link>
                    </Col>
                    <Col md={3}>
                      <Button
                        onClick={() =>
                          updateCartHandler(item, item.quantity - 1)
                        }
                        variant="light"
                        disabled={item.quantity === 1}
                      >
                        <i className="fas fa-minus-circle"></i>
                      </Button>{' '}
                      <span>{item.quantity}</span>{' '}
                      <Button
                        variant="light"
                        onClick={() =>
                          updateCartHandler(item, item.quantity + 1)
                        }
                        disabled={item.quantity === item.countInStock}
                      >
                        <i className="fas fa-plus-circle"></i>
                      </Button>
                    </Col>
                    <Col md={3}>${item.price}</Col>
                    <Col md={2}>
                      <Button
                        onClick={() => removeItemHandler(item)}
                        variant="light"
                      >
                        <i className="fas fa-trash"></i>
                      </Button>
                    </Col>
                  </Row>
                </ListGroup.Item>
              ))}
            </ListGroup>
          )}
        </Col>
        <Col md={4}>
          <Card>
            <Card.Body>
              <ListGroup variant="flush">
                <ListGroup.Item>
                  <h3>
                    Subtotal ({cartItems.reduce((a, c) => a + c.quantity, 0)}{' '}
                    items) : $
                    {cartItems.reduce((a, c) => a + c.price * c.quantity, 0)}
                  </h3>
                </ListGroup.Item>
                <ListGroup.Item>
                  <div className="d-grid">
                    <Button
                      type="button"
                      variant="primary"
                      onClick={checkoutHandler}
                      disabled={cartItems.length === 0}
                    >
                      Proceed to Checkout
                    </Button>
                  </div>
                </ListGroup.Item>
              </ListGroup>
            </Card.Body>
          </Card>
        </Col>
      </Row>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Actually I attempted to follow the instructions from the reactjs.org website on lists-and-keys but it was unsuccessful and I really didnt know how to go about it.

Comment: at a glance this looks OK as far as the `key` is concerned. Are you sure that all the `item._id` properties in your data are actually unique? (We can't possibly tell that from the code you've shown.)

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34576332/warning-each-child-in-an-array-or-iterator-should-have-a-unique-key-prop-che) answers your question?

Comment: For my data _id: is set to a string starting from  '1' and then increasing numerically for each product. I solved the issue regarding the error however the functionality of the CartScreen is still giving me problems. I want it to function like any other website where you can add multiple items to the cart. Instead of adding various items, it replaces the current item. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You've got duplicate ids. change it to `cartItems.map((item, i) => ...)` and use i for the key.

Comment: Thanks! This did get rid of the error, however, I'm still having a functionality issue. When I add items to the cart instead of that item being added, it just replaces the other one.

Comment: I can't go into that too much but it should look something like: `onClick={() => setCartItems([...cartItems, item])}`

Comment: Ok, I know you said you can't really go into that but where would I might add that? I have onClicks for my increase /decrease quantity buttons, and one for removeItemHanlder, but where would I add that?

Comment: to the add to cart button, but that would require you to redo your cart to make it simpler

Comment: ok thats fine. I actually posted another more in-depth question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75467086/im-unable-to-add-multiple-items-to-my-cart