# I'm unable to add multiple items to my cart

Tags: javascript, reactjs, e-commerce, mern

I'm creating an e-commerce website and I've run into an issue that I'm having trouble solving. The functionality to add products to the cart, route to `CartScreen`, and be able to `increase/decrease` quantity and remove items from the cart all work. However, if there is an item in the cart and I want to add another, instead of having both items in the cart it replaces the first item with the second and copies its quantity. Does anyone have any idea how I can fix this?

Here is my Product.js:

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
import Card from 'react-bootstrap/Card';
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import Rating from './Rating';
import axios from 'axios';
import { useContext } from 'react';
import { Store } from '../Store';

function Product(props) {
  const { product } = props;

  const { state, dispatch: ctxDispatch } = useContext(Store);
  const {
    cart: { cartItems },
  } = state;
        
  const addToCartHandler = async (item) => {
    const existItem = cartItems.find((x) => x._id === product._id);
    const quantity = existItem ? existItem.quantity + 1 : 1;
    const { data } = await axios.get(`/api/products/${item._id}`);
    if (data.countInStock < quantity) {
      window.alert('Sorry. Product is out of stock');
      return;
    }
    ctxDispatch({
      type: 'CART_ADD_ITEM',
      payload: { ...item, quantity },
    });
  };

  return (
    <Card>
      <Link to={`/product/${product.slug}`}>
        <img src={product.image} className="card-img-top" alt={product.name} />
      </Link>
      <Card.Body>
        <Link to={`/product/${product.slug}`}>
          <Card.Title>{product.name}</Card.Title>
        </Link>
        <Rating rating={product.rating} numReviews={product.numReviews} />
        <Card.Text>${product.price}</Card.Text>
        {product.countInStock === 0 ? (
          <Button variant="light" disabled>
            Out of stock
          </Button>
        ) : (
          <Button onClick={() => addToCartHandler(product)}>Add to cart</Button>
        )}
      </Card.Body>
    </Card>
  );
                
}
export default Product;
```

Here is my CartScreen.js:

```
import { useContext } from 'react';
import { Store } from '../Store';
import { Helmet } from 'react-helmet-async';
import Row from 'react-bootstrap/Row';
import Col from 'react-bootstrap/Col';
import MessageBox from '../components/MessageBox';
import ListGroup from 'react-bootstrap/ListGroup';
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';
import Card from 'react-bootstrap/Card';
import { Link, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import axios from 'axios';
export default function CartScreen() {
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    const { state, dispatch: ctxDispatch } = useContext(Store);
    const {
      cart: { cartItems },
    } = state;

    const updateCartHandler = async (item, quantity) => {
      const { data } = await axios.get(`/api/products/${item._id}`);
      if (data.countInStock < quantity) {
        window.alert('Sorry. Product is out of stock');
        return;
      }
      ctxDispatch({
        type: 'CART_ADD_ITEM',
        payload: { ...item, quantity },
      });
    };
    const removeItemHandler = (item) => {
      ctxDispatch({ type: 'CART_REMOVE_ITEM', payload: item });
    };

    const checkoutHandler = () => {
      navigate('/signin?redirect=/shipping');
    };

    return (
      <div>
        <Helmet>
          <title>Shopping Cart</title>
        </Helmet>
        <h1>Shopping Cart</h1>
        <Row>
          <Col md={8}>
            {cartItems.length === 0 ? (
              <MessageBox>
                Cart is empty. <Link to="/">Go Shopping</Link>
              </MessageBox>
            ) : (
              <ListGroup>
                {cartItems.map((item, i) => (
                  <ListGroup.Item key={i}>
                    <Row className="align-items-center">
                      <Col md={4}>
                        <img
                          src={item.image}
                          alt={item.name}
                          className="img-fluid rounded img-thumbnail"
                        ></img>{' '}
                        <Link to={`/product/${item.slug}`}>{item.name}</Link>
                      </Col>
                      <Col md={3}>
                        <Button
                          onClick={() =>
                            updateCartHandler(item, item.quantity - 1)
                          }
                          variant="light"
                          disabled={item.quantity === 1}
                        >
                          <i className="fas fa-minus-circle"></i>
                        </Button>{' '}
                        <span>{item.quantity}</span>{' '}
                        <Button
                          variant="light"
                          onClick={() =>
                            updateCartHandler(item, item.quantity + 1)
                          }
                          disabled={item.quantity === item.countInStock}
                        >
                          <i className="fas fa-plus-circle"></i>
                        </Button>
                      </Col>
                      <Col md={3}>${item.price}</Col>
                      <Col md={2}>
                        <Button
                          onClick={() => removeItemHandler(item)}
                          variant="light"
                        >
                          <i className="fas fa-trash"></i>
                        </Button>
                      </Col>
                    </Row>
                  </ListGroup.Item>
                ))}
              </ListGroup>
            )}
          </Col>
          <Col md={4}>
            <Card>
              <Card.Body>
                <ListGroup variant="flush">
                  <ListGroup.Item>
                    <h3>
                      Subtotal ({cartItems.reduce((a, c) => a + c.quantity, 0)}{' '}
                      items) : $
                      {cartItems.reduce((a, c) => a + c.price * c.quantity, 0)}
                    </h3>
                  </ListGroup.Item>
                  <ListGroup.Item>
                    <div className="d-grid">
                      <Button
                        type="button"
                        variant="primary"
                        onClick={checkoutHandler}
                        disabled={cartItems.length === 0}
                      >
                        Proceed to Checkout
                      </Button>
                    </div>
                  </ListGroup.Item>
                </ListGroup>
              </Card.Body>
            </Card>
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

This is my Store.js:

```
import { createContext, useReducer } from 'react';
                
export const Store = createContext();
                
const initialState = {
  cart: {
    cartItems: localStorage.getItem('cartItems')
      ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cartItems'))
      : [],
  },
};

function reducer(state, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'CART_ADD_ITEM':
       // add to cart
       const newItem = action.payload;
       const existItem = state.cart.cartItems.find(
         (item) => item._id === newItem._id
       );
       const cartItems = existItem
         ? state.cart.cartItems.map((item) =>
             item._id === existItem._id ? newItem : item
           )
        : [...state.cart.cartItems, newItem];
      localStorage.setItem('cartItems', JSON.stringify(cartItems));
      return { ...state, cart: { ...state.cart, cartItems } };
    case 'CART_REMOVE_ITEM': {
      const cartItems = state.cart.cartItems.filter(
        (item) => item._id !== action.payload._id
      );
      localStorage.setItem('cartItems', JSON.stringify(cartItems));
      return { ...state, cart: { ...state.cart, cartItems } };
    }
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export function StoreProvider(props) {
    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);
    const value = { state, dispatch };
    return <Store.Provider value={value}>{props.children} </Store.Provider>;
}
```

Before in the `CartScreen` I was getting an Error of child in the list should be a unique key prop. But after fixing the issue still remains so I guess that wasn't the issue.

Comment: I think it's related to your items having the same _id. So check your product data.

Comment: for my product data i have _id: '1' the _id:'2', etc. Is it because there are strings perhaps?

Comment: we know from the earlier question that some of your products have the same id so check your product data and fix whatever is wrong there