# Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop. Check the render method of `ScrollPage`

Tags: react-native, warnings

this is the render function

```
    export function RenderSection({initSection,response,setResponse}) {
log("rendersection");
if (initSection.body) {
    log('initSection.body.type : ',initSection.body.type);
}
const [_visible,setVisible] = React.useState(true);
const remove = () => {
    log('removing section');
    //setVisible(false);
    let newSections:any = [];
    for (let section of response.sections) {
        if (section.key != initSection.key) {
            newSections.push(section);
        }
    }
    setResponse({
        sections: newSections,
        prop:response.prop,
        header:response.header,
        init:true,
        loaded:true
    });

}
```

this is the part where function is called

```
    const scrollingContent = React.useMemo(()=>{
       
       
        return <View>
            {response.sections.map(section=>{
                return <fn.RenderSection initSection={section} response={response} setResponse={setResponse} />;
            } ) }
                
        </View>;
       
    }
    ,[response]);
```

this is sections:

```
    [{"body": {"children": [Array], "prop": [Object], "type": "view"}}]
```

and this json from the website

```
    {"status":"ok","header":[],"prop":{"bgimg":null,"bgcolor":"#5f97cf"},"sections":[{"body":{"type":"view","children":[{"type":"text","child":"My Jcow Network","prop":{"style":[["font-size","40px"],["color","white"],["text-shadow","1px 1px 4px #666666"]]},"key":"64b152ee0232d"},{"type":"text","child":"This is a Social Network","prop":{"style":[["font-size","30px"],["color","white"],["text-shadow","1px 1px 4px #666666"]]},"key":"64b152ee02332"},{"type":"button","prop":{"title":"Create account","type":"link","color_type":"bold","uri":"member\/signup"},"key":"64b152ee02402"},{"type":"line_break","0":"key\"=> uniqid()"},{"type":"button","prop":{"title":"Login","type":"link","uri":"member\/login"},"key":"64b152ee024c2"}],"prop":{"style":[["height","610px"],["margin","20px"],["justify-content","center"],["flex-direction","column"]],"type":"column"}},"title":null,"key":"995cbe34042e7590419d13b97e312608","bgcolor":"transparent","platforms":["web","app"]}]}
```

where this key is missing? I'm new to react-native

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Warning: Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop. Check the render method of \`ListView\`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34576332/warning-each-child-in-an-array-or-iterator-should-have-a-unique-key-prop-che)

Comment: no, it doesn't.